# How can I use a result of command as a var in a child of input

Tags: mysql, shell, ssh

SHELL code as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
..// etc
ssh root@127.0.0.1 << EOF    
KEYS=$(mysql -h ${DB_IP} -u ${USERNAME} -p${PASSWORD} -P ${DB_PORT}  --database bosdb -e "select a from B where id=1");
echo "123";
echo $KEYS;
... // etc
EOF
```

When I run this script, the output text is

```
123
(this is a NULL line, that means KEYS is null)
```

I have tried if I log in to the machine of MYSQL directly, I can get the result of the "MYSQL" command, and the echo $KEYS also shows a string of values. But when I used subcommand as input, it didn't work.
So, how can I get the value of KEYS correctly? I'd really appreciate if someone can help me

Comment: try to use `set -xv` inside the ssh stanza and even outside to debug your code.

Comment: @Jerryzhou : You don't get any error message either? `mysql` should at least deliver **some** other information. What happens, when you run **inside the _here_-document** (and before assigning to `KEY`) just the plain `mysql` command first (without assigning its stdout to a variable). Do you see any output?

Comment: @Jerryzhou : In addition, you could do - because I'm paranoid in this respect - write the assignment to `KEYS` as `KEYS=$(mysql 2>&1 -h ${DB_IP} .... )`, and also do a `which mysql` before (or afterwards).

Comment: The output showed "mysql: command not found" before I put set -xv inside the ssh. When I added `set -xv`, I also found the reference variables were null. Fortunately, I found another way. Here is code `printf -v db_ip %q DB_IP ..... ssh .... "bash -s $db_ip " << 'EOF' ... KEYS=$(mysql-h $1` ，it worked. I believe that the variables defined in the parent shell didn't transfer to the child shell